# Is quantum randomness just epistemic uncertainty of the microstates of macroscopic systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-measurements

As far as I can tell, randomness in QM occurs when a classical measurement is made.  Classical measurements involve macroscopic systems.  We cannot know the detailed microstates of these systems.  How can we tell that the random outcomes of quantum measurements are not related to the details of the measurement device?

The hypothesis I’m entertaining goes something like this: The laws of physics are quantum mechanical, and described by deterministic unitary propagation. [and] The apparent randomness that occurs in classical outcomes is due to the fact that we don’t know the exact microscopic state of of everything that comprises the experimental set up.

Comment: No, this isn't how quantum randomness arises. If the direction a photon is deflected can be read off the state of a beam splitter, then this collapses the superposition -- the beam splitter measures which way the photon is going. And conversely, if your photon is in a genuine superposition, of the kind you can use to perform interference experiments with, then the which-way information is _not_ encoded in the beam splitter, not even in principle.

Comment: @knzhou how do we know that the which way information is not encoded in the beam splitter? If this has been shown, then it would be an answer to my question.

Comment: @Dave It can be (and has been) shown in quantum theory. Is that what you're looking for? It can also be shown independently of quantum theory, using the fact that the real world violates certain inequalities that are satisfied in all noncontextual hidden variable models, but the last paragraph in the question seems to exclude such demonstrations. Is that the intent?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly What I’m thinking is like this: the probability of the outcomes is just like we compute using QM - these probabilities satisfy the Bell inequalities. The details of what particular outcome occurs at which particular times (in EPR whether we get a coincidence or not) is a function of the unknown state of the macroscopic components that are interacting with the quantum system being tested.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I’m assuming QM everywhere.  Then all we have are wavefuntions (more accurately a vector in h-space) propagating around; where it ends up, i.e. whether it ends up in a state corresponding to the classical/macroscopic state “deflected up” (stern-Gerlach) is just the result of the details of the initial state and the interaction.  Neither of which we  know in detail if there is a macroscopic system in the mix.

Comment: @Dave But that's the whole point of Bell inequalities: their violation shows that this idea can't work. Bell inequalities are important precisely because they don't depend on quantum theory: they only depend on the idea of local (or noncontextual) hidden variables, so if they're violated, as they are in the real world, then that idea can't be right. (This doesn't rule out the possibility that the quantum state is epistemic -- it doesn't rule out the possibility of hidden variables -- but it does rule out exclusively *local* or *noncontextual* hidden variables, as suggested in the question.)

Comment: @Dave Bell inequalities allow for unknown details in the measuring device, not just in the thing being measured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118217/discussion-between-dave-and-chiral-anomaly).

Comment: haven't read it yet, but I think this might be getting at what I'm looking for: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01909939 (note how the abstract mentions how the precision of control of the macroscopic degrees of freedom to the resulting loss in coherence)

Answer (score 2):

Quantum randomness is not just epistemic uncertainty of the microstates of macroscopic measuring devices.

Or at least, since it's hard to completely logically disprove almost anything, it might be better to say that the price we would have to pay for accepting the above hypothesis is enormous.

Why? Let's consider the Bell experiment, where the two entangled particles are sent to the opposite sides of the galaxy, and let's examine two versions of the hypothesis:

**Hypothesis 1. The result of measuring each particle is fully determined by the state of the apparatus interacting with it, independently of the state of affairs on the other side of the galaxy.**

Then there would be local hidden variables (namely, the exact state of the measurement device) that would determine measurement outcomes. But Bell's theorem rules out local hidden variables, if the predictions of QM are correct.

So the price we have to pay for accepting this hypothesis is having to deny the predictions of QM.

**Hypothesis 2. The result of measuring each particle is fully determined by the states of both apparatuses.**

Then let's fix the state of the apparatus measuring particle $A$ to be $\alpha_0$. Then Alice's result (she measures $A$) is a function of $\beta$, the state of Bob's apparatus. Suppose some state $\beta_{up}$ results in spin up for $A$, and $\beta_{down}$ results in spin down. But that means information about which of these two states Bob's apparatus on the other side of the galaxy was in is now encoded in the result of Alice's measurement. I.e. information travels faster than light (even if it's hard to extract it)!

So the price we have to pay for accepting hypothesis 2 is having to deny **relativistic locality**.

Note: Relativistic non-locality is different, and far "worse" than the usual quantum non-locality, aka EPR/Bell-nonlocality, aka "spooky action at a distance".

Comment: Who said anything about locality?

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page, the logic of  my proof is as follows: if we assume your hypothesis, then it follows that there are local hidden variables. In other words, if your hypothesis is true then bells theorem is violated.

Comment: If there are two  or more macroscopic optical components (mirrors beam splitters whatever) in the experiment that are interacting with the entangled particles, the outcome of the experiment is a  function of all of their states.  Non local.

Comment: Perhaps we should clarify that it's actual experimental evidence that rules out local hidden variables, not a "theorem".

Comment: Dave, perhaps you could clarify your hypothesis for me. I assumed that your hypothesis does not allow for violations of **relativistic** locality, i. e. for the possibility of transmitting **information** faster than light. Was my assumption correct? My response will depend on that. Note that I'm specifically asking about relativistic locality, not locality in the bell/EPR sense.

Comment: I updated my answer with both responses.

Comment: States $\beta_{up}, \beta_{down}$ arise when bob’s instrument interacts with particle B, which is entangled with particle A.  The final states of the detectors are connected since both interact with the entangled quantum particles.  This seems to me like “regular” spooky action at a distance.

Comment: Those states I defined were supposed to represent states of Bob's apparatus before any measurements.

Comment: @Dave : Relativistic non-locality runs into the possibility of a causality violation, and thus logical inconsistencies of the form of the grandfather paradox.

Comment: @ReasonMeThis what we know is that Bob’s device went from state beta to beta’ after interacting with the entangled particles and Alice’s device went from alpha to alpha’ after interacting with the entangled particles, and these states correspond to a particular classical outcome.  We do the experiment again.  Now B goes from delta to delta’ and Alice’s goes from gamma to gamma’and a different (or the same) classical outcome occurs.

Comment: We can’t re-run the experiment with intital states alpha,beta because macroscopic things never (in practice)return to the exact same state.  Maybe if we could and did, we’d end up with deterministic classical outcomes.

Comment: I think I can agree with all of that, but I don't see this  disrupting any step in the proof of the relativistic non-locality. Let me know if I am missing something, and which step in the proof you believe is incorrect.

Comment: @ReasonMeThis how does Alice know that the available initial states to bobs device are beta up/down?

Comment: Oh, Alice doesn’t need to know anything. She wouldn’t be able to extract this information probably. But we don’t care about Alice. The point of the proof was to demonstrate that information about Bob's device is now encoded in the results of Alice's measurements (even if she doesn't have the knowhow to extract it), which is sufficient to violate relativistic locality.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to interpret the probabilities one gets from quantum mechanics. Because of Bell Inequality violations, we interpret them to be fundamental rather than related to ignorance. This interpretation carries over to the cases where there are no such Bell-violations issues. You *could* choose to intrepret the probability in such cases to be due to ignorance, but you would need to have *just the right* microscopic states and interactions to match the quantum probabilties, and *in addition* that whenever the situation does probe locality then, by cosmic but certain coincidence, the fundamental (non-ignorance) probabilities arise. That's... a rather convoluted philosophy. Better to just accept that the probabilities are fundamental as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

Muon decay is a case where there is randomness, an individual muon’s lifetime as well as the details of the decay products, but where no interaction with a macroscopic system is required.  Muons are interchangeable and have no internal structure, so the fact that different instances decay differently is intrinsic quantum randomness.

(Though you can start to go down the “if a muon passes through a forest, and no one detects an electron, did it really decay?” Line of thought).

Comment: Not entirely: you can say the state of the muon field just gradually gets entangled with the electron and neutrino fields, in a totally deterministic way. It only gets collapsed upon interaction with a detector, at which point you can interpret the result as the muon decaying some time earlier.

Comment: @knzhou that’s what I was getting at with the parenthetical comment)